# Split TOC in classicthesis

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

I'm trying to find a way to split the TOC in classicthesis, so that I don't have the contents of the appendices appearing in the main TOC (just their titles), but rather in a separate TOC before the appendices.  This is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt, titlepage, headinclude, footinclude, numbers=noenddot, cleardoublepage=empty]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers, beramono, eulermath, pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

%TOC (as coded in classicthesis download)
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}
% Set the numbering level to be shown: part=-1, chapter=0, section=1, subsection=2, subsubsection=3, paragraph=4, subparagraph=5.
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % <-- 2 = up to subsections in the ToC
% \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % <-- 3 = numbers up to subsubsections in the text
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textsc{\thesection}\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}

\part{Main Text}
\blinddocument

\part{Appendices}
\appendix
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

As you can see, on the TOC page, Appendix A gets a full listing (where I'd prefer \setcounter{tocdepth}{0}), and I can't see any way to repeat another TOC before the appendices (with \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}).

I've done this with other documents by combining tocloft and titletoc, but classicthesis doesn't use the latter (I think).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the simplest way of stopping the sections etc being listed is to insert `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}` after `\appendix`.

This is a bit of a blunt weapon, though, because it still leaves the issue of doing a separate TOC for the Appendices.  I've experimented with `etoc`, and that goes part of the way.

Long MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt, titlepage, headinclude, footinclude, numbers=noenddot, cleardoublepage=empty]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers, beramono, eulermath, pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}  % Number up to subsubsection level.
\pagenumbering{roman}

% Short TOC - chapters and sections only.
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}  % Set depth to section in the (short) table of contents.
\etocsettocstyle{\chapter*{Short Contents}}{}  % Heading for the short toc.
\localtableofcontents

% Long TOC - down to subsubsection.
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}  % Set depth to subsubsection in the (long) table of contents.
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Long Contents}
\etocsettocstyle{\chapter*{Long Contents}}{}  % Heading for the long toc.
\localtableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\etocsettocstyle{\section*{Contents of Chapter \thechapter}}{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\vskip0.5\baselineskip}  % Chapter TOC

\chapter{Chapter One}
\localtableofcontents
\section{One}
\blindtext
\subsection{One-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{One-One-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{One-One-Two}
\blindtext
\subsection{One-Two}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{One-Two-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{One-Two-Two}
\blindtext
\section{Two}
\blindtext
\subsection{Two-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Two-One-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Two-One-Two}
\blindtext
\subsection{Two-Two}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Two-Two-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Two-Two-Two}
\blindtext

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\localtableofcontents
\section{One}
\blindtext
\subsection{One-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{One-One-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{One-One-Two}
\blindtext
\subsection{One-Two}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{One-Two-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{One-Two-Two}
\blindtext
\section{Two}
\blindtext
\subsection{Two-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Two-One-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Two-One-Two}
\blindtext
\subsection{Two-Two}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Two-Two-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Two-Two-Two}
\blindtext

\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}  % Set the display depth for the TOC to chapter only.

% List of appendices.
\etocsettocstyle{\vskip0.3\baselineskip\chapter*{Appendices}}{}  % Heading for the list of appendices.
\localtableofcontents

\chapter{Appendix A}
\section{One}
\blindtext
\subsection{One-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{One-One-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{One-One-Two}
\blindtext
\subsection{One-Two}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{One-Two-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{One-Two-Two}
\blindtext
\section{Two}
\blindtext
\subsection{Two-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Two-One-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Two-One-Two}
\blindtext
\subsection{Two-Two}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Two-Two-One}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Two-Two-Two}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

This allows additional TOCs (I have a short and a long one here), and partial TOCs for each chapter.

However, there are still a few wrinkles.

(1) The page-numbering is incorrect.  The first page of the long TOC gets a Roman numeral, meaning that the main text starts on p2 instead of p1.

(2) The TOC for the appendices is empty.  This is bizarre, because on my "real" document, it has a line for Appendix A, and the EXACT same commands are used.

(3) The fact that `tocdepth` is set to 0 before the appendices presumably means that the section etc data is not logged to the TOC file, and this means that etoc cannot therefore access section data for the appendices.  At any rate, a partial TOC for each appendix is not possible.

So, a bit farther forward, but still with issues that mean it's not really a robust solution.